# Svg icon is clickable on every browser except for on firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, svg

I have an SVG icon that We use so users can add reviews to our service. Normally the user clicks on the icon and the onClick event is fired and everything works fine. This behavior is consistent on every browser except for om firefox where no onClick is fired when the rating SVG is clicked.

I have tried putting the onClick on the SVG tag and the g tag and it works fine on safari, chrome, and opera but none of that works on firefox.

```
const Rating = ({ color, onclick, ...props }) => (
  <svg id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 80 80" {...props}>
    <g className="st0" onClick={onclick}>
      <path className="st1" d="M0 0h80v80H0z" />
    </g>
    <path
      className={color}
      /* eslint max-len: ["error", 500] */
      d="M22.9 67.6c-.6 0-1.2-.2-1.8-.6-.9-.7-1.4-1.8-1.2-2.9l3-17.5-12.7-12.4c-.8-.8-1.1-2-.8-3.1.4-1.1 1.3-1.9 2.4-2l17.5-2.5 7.8-15.9c1-2 4.4-2 5.4 0l7.8 15.9L68 29.1c1.1.2 2.1 1 2.4 2s.1 2.3-.8 3.1L57 46.6 60 64c.2 1.1-.3 2.3-1.2 2.9-.9.7-2.1.8-3.2.2L40 59l-15.7 8.2c-.5.2-.9.4-1.4.4zm17.1-15c.5 0 1 .1 1.4.3L53.1 59l-2.2-13c-.2-1 .2-2 .9-2.7l9.5-9.2-13.1-1.9c-1-.1-1.8-.8-2.3-1.6L40 18.8l-5.8 11.9c-.4.9-1.3 1.5-2.3 1.6l-13.1 1.9 9.5 9.2c.7.7 1 1.7.9 2.7l-2.2 13L38.7 53c.3-.3.8-.4 1.3-.4z"
    />
  </svg>
)

Rating.propTypes = {
    color: PropTypes.string,
}

export default Rating

  <Rating
  key={_.uniqueId(i)}
  className="star-rating__star"
  onClick={() => this.rate(i)}
  viewBox="0 0 90 90"
  />
```

I expect an onClick event to be fired when the SVG is clicked just like it does on every other major browser.

Update: After some debugging in inspect elements I found the stars do not become clickable because in one context they are rendered inside of a button even do though the button does not have any click event.

Comment: Did you try to wrap the svg element inside a div?

Comment: It seems that this has nothing to do with the SVG itself, as that works fine in Firefox. https://jsfiddle.net/qe3o1w8m/

Comment: Your click event is on the rect behind the star. The event won't fire when clicking the fill of the star. Add pointer-events:none for the star.

Comment: what about moving the onClick to the svg element? It seems to occupy the same area when I look at the viewBox values and the path values where the onClick is.